# ListView control for Silverlight 4?

Tags: listview, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

It seems like Silverlight 4 does not have a ListView control, unless I am missing something.  Or a control that's basically replicates its function (e.g. re-sizable column headers, etc...).

Is there an example of how to create something similar?  I am after a setup like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DataGrid control. It has re-sizable column headers, column-click ordering, grouping, in-place editing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For your case a DataGrid makes sence as Rafa already stated. 
Just for reference issues, an equivalent to ListView for Silverlight would be ItemsControl.